# CUDA support for RTX 3080 (Laptop GeForce Notebook Products)

Tags: laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, ubuntu-20.04

Does RTX 3080 for laptops already support CUDA and cuDNN for Deep learning requirements? I want to buy a new Razor Blade 15 with RTX 3080 and I don’t see currently any listing of this GPU on Nvidia [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

The goal is to install CUDA on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does RTX 3080 for laptops already support CUDA and cuDNN for Deep learning requirements?

CUDA enabled GeForce products support CUDA compute level 8.6 which is support by [CUDA Toolkit 11.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html)

| GPU | Compute Capability |
| --- | --- |
| GeForce RTX 3090 | 8.6 |
| GeForce RTX 3080 | 8.6 |
| GeForce RTX 3070 | 8.6 |

Source:

- [CUDA-Enabled GeForce and TITAN Products](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute)
- [GeForce 30 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_30_series)

Comment: I would provide a link [Deep Learning](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/index.html) documentation but I can't view it so that would be sort of pointless.

Comment: It's so doubtful to come to a direct answer, mainly because I still don't see any direct listing RTX 30_series for notebooks to support certain CUDA versions. Maybe because I am used to distingue them with the letter "M" for mobile. Thanks a lot for your answer it's crisp and clear!

Comment: @SašoPavlič - Mobile 30 series GPUs are still considered to use the Ampere architecture. Since desktop and mobile products of the same series use the same architecture their capabilities are nearly identical.  The one key difference between mobile and desktop products, is that mobile products, often have the capability to dynamically change the frequency

Answer (score 2):

The latest NVIDIA RTX line can do anything that the previous lines could do, and more,
but needs at least CUDA Toolkit 11.1.

References:

- [CUDA Toolkit 11.1 Introduces Support for GeForce RTX 30 Series and Quadro RTX Series GPUs](https://news.developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-1-introduces-support-rtx-30-series/)
- [Best GPU for deep learning in 2020-2021: RTX 3090 vs. RTX 3080 vs. TITAN RTX vs. RTX 2080 Ti benchmarks (FP32, FP16)](https://bizon-tech.com/blog/best-gpu-for-deep-learning-rtx-3090-vs-rtx-3080-vs-titan-rtx-vs-rtx-2080-ti)

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if, for example, previous lines can do something if the new one is just built on top of it. It's also interesting for me, that I don't see any specific mention which supports the question if the same goes for the laptop version GPUs.